# In Notepad++, how can I set "Highlight Tag Matching" to work with PHP Syntax endif, endforeach; etc.?

Tags: php, notepad++

In Notepad++ (which I love using) I typically write PHP statements in this syntax

```
<?php if ($something == 'is_cool'):
// Do it
endif; ?>
```

As opposed to

```
<?php if ($something == 'is_cool'){
// Do it
} ?>
```

Same goes for endforeach; and the like. The problem is in Notepad++ it will highlight matching brackets {} but not matching if, endif / foreach, endforeach / so on so forth...

Is there a way to set it so it will match and highlight the start and end of these types of statements when I click on one or the other? I've played around a bit in the preferences and ticked off a checkbox for "highlight comment/php/asp zone" thinking that might do it but alas it was not so. For whatever it's worth the matching highlight works like a champ with plain old HTML (minus some HTML5 tags but no biggie).

I suspect I might be able to do it with the User Defined Language tool but it's honestly kind of a crazy looking interface... and I don't want to invest time diving into it unless I know it will do what I'm looking for. It seems like if I use that tool I have define ALL the opening and closing tags, which seems like a lot of excess work for just wanting to match a few commonly used one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are searching is not implemented in N++ to date. You can easily check it is not present also for other languages such as C# or Visual Basic. If you wish to get functionalities tailored closer to the PHP, please consider some PHP IDE instead of N++. Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312023/is-there-a-php-syntax-checker-for-notepad), it contains related answers, too.

Comment: Thanks for info and link. It was helpful. I'm loathe to move away from notepad++ because I am just so used to it but I'm exploring other IDEs currently.